# What does "Screenshot Quality" do?

Tags: overwatch

I've noticed that Overwatch offers a graphics option called "Screenshot Quality". I've set the quality to 9x resolution and taken a screenshot using the <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> key on my keyboard.

After looking at the screenshot, I have to wonder what the option did exactly. The screenshot's resolution is the same as the resolution I play at, and since I can still see aliasing, it's obvious the internal resolution wasn't increased before taking the shot.

Since I can't find a "Screenshot Key" in the Controls option, I can't tell if the <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> key was the correct key to press, though.

What does the "Screenshot Quality" do exactly, and how would I take a screenshot to properly see its effects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To take a screenshot, [you press the <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> (Print Screen) button](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/200569).

According to Bruce, a senior engineer at Overwatch, [he posted on the forums this tidbit](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:k81MXTlT2csJ:us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20742905893%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> How to use – in the Graphics Option menu, under the Advanced items,
>   there is a new setting called “Screenshot Quality”. **Basically this
>   setting controls the tile count of the screenshot**. At 1x, screenshots
>   are saved like we always have done – includes UI, saved in jpeg
>   format, at the current resolution of the game. Once you select 3x
>   through 9x resolution, you’ll enable high quality screenshot mode.

In addition, there are specific settings you must have enabled in order to make the most use of Screenshot Quality:

> There are some restrictions on high quality screenshots to keep in
>   mind. UI doesn’t render in a high quality screenshot. This mode only
>   works in windowed mode and borderless windowed mode. High quality
>   screenshots aren’t compressed, they are saved in BMP format. Finally,
>   this can be taxing on your computer. Consider that creating a 9x
>   resolution screenshot of a standard 1920x1080 display will create a
>   very large 17280x9720 BMP file on your hard drive, so make sure you
>   have both the memory and hard drive space for your screenshots before
>   enabling this feature.

Comment: Nice. The problem wasn't that I hit the wrong key, but that the game saved those screenshots in a weird place, while Windows saved its own (native res) copy in OneDrive's pictures library. That confused me, and I didn't think about looking anywhere else for the screenshot.